# How do I get the selected value of the second dropdown from the first dropdown via MY-SQL?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I want to get the first dropdown menu to get the selected value for the selected dropbox, but I would like to to have all the categories still being in the second dropbox, so I can change the category of the article.

For example, the user chooses a article in the first dropbox, then the category that is associated with that article gets selected, but the user can change the category in the dropbox. Can this be done?

I have tried using Javascript from a previous question , but it's only getting the selected category associated with that article and not all the other categories. What should I do? Does anyone know how this can be done?

```
<?php   $link = mysqli_connect("160.153.129.204", "username", "password", "lvo92");

  $db = new mysqli("160.153.129.204", "laurensvo92", "90F0411553l", "lvo92");//set your database handler
  $query = "SELECT catid, titel FROM artikelen";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $categories[] = array("catid" => $row['catid'], "val" => $row['titel']);
  }

  $query = "SELECT catid, cat FROM Categorie";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $subcats[$row['catid']][] = array("catid" => $row['catid'], "val" => $row['cat']);
  }

  $jsonCats = json_encode($categories);
  $jsonSubCats = json_encode($subcats);


?>          

     <script type='text/javascript'>
      <?php
        echo "var categories = $jsonCats; \n";
        echo "var subcats = $jsonSubCats; \n";
      ?>
      function loadCategories(){
        var select = document.getElementById("categoriesSelect");
        select.onchange = updateSubCats;
        for(var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
          select.options[i] = new Option(categories[i].val,categories[i].catid);          
        }
      }
   function updateSubCats(){
    var catSelect = this;
    var catid = this.value;
    var testSelectionArray = new Array();

for(var j = 0; j < this.options.length; j++) {
      if (this.options[j].selected) {
           testSelectionArray.push(this.options[j].value); 
       }
}

    var subcatSelect = document.getElementById("subcatsSelect");
    subcatSelect.options.length = 0; //delete all options if any present
    var k=0;
    for(var i = 0; i < testSelectionArray.length; i++){
      catid = testSelectionArray[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < subcats[catid].length; j++){
            subcatSelect.options[k++] = new Option(subcats[catid][j].val,subcats[catid][j].catid);
        }        
    }
  }
    </script>

     <body onload='loadCategories()'>
    <select id='categoriesSelect'>
    </select>

    <select id='subcatsSelect'>
        </select>
```

Comment: As mentioned, I would start with this `SELECT c.catid
     , a.titel
     , c.cat 
  FROM artikelen a
  JOIN Categorie c
    ON c.catid = a.catid` and handle the rest in code

Comment: The Logic is the part i’m trying to wrok out. I’m not a expert in JavaScript.

Comment: Here's several methods... https://css-tricks.com/examples/DynamicDropdown/

Comment: Database part of the script in that link doesn't work and I'm really new to Javascript.

Comment: Actually, on closer inspection, that's a terrible example - but I'm sure that there are lots of other examples out there of transforming a result set into a bit of json.